# How to add icons on both buttons of the jQuery Mobile Split Button List item?

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement a list of contacts for a chat application. (jQuery 2.1.0, jQuery Mobile 1.4.2)

I started with below code, which gives me an icon on the left of the contact item.(used to show status.)

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Item 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ud8j92he/

Now, I want to extend it and use a split button list to add a button on the right to edit/delete the contact.

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="edit" data-split-theme="c">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a> 
      <a href="#">Edit</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b84zuf6w/

But with split button list, I cannot add the icon to the left of the first button. If I use 'ui btn' with split button list, it overrides and I do not get the edit button on the right.

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="edit" data-split-theme="c">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Item 1</a> 
      <a href="#">Edit</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, how do I combine both to have an icon on the left, and the split button on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it without jQuery Mobile Split Button List in the end.

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li class="ui-li-has-alt">
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Item 1</a> 
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-edit ui-btn-c" title="Edit"></a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1k3d0uee/